# Which error events do no trigger window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

MDN [states the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror):

> some/many `error` events do not trigger `window.onerror`, you have to
> listen for them specifically

That's great, but which ones do not invoke [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)?

Comment: If a program cannot be parsed, then you get a `SyntaxError` before the `onerror` assignment can even be evaluated.

Comment: Let's assume that the first script loaded only has `window.onerror=function(){console.log(arguments);};` and nothing more.

Comment: I assume that bit in the MDN docs refers to loading `error` events for Ajax, images, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like quirksmode has a good detail of what errors it will and will not catch: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

If it helps, any error that you specifically `throw` will be caught.

Comment: Thanks, Shmiddty, I'll take a look at the page you linked. I'm more interested in errors that are thrown by the compiler.

Comment: `any error that you specifically throw will be caught` is that true even when in async calls?