# window.onerror does not catch DOMException

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-logging, domexception

I am running an angularjs application on a chrome browser and want to log all the errors that are thrown.
I am using the following in order to do that:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
        alert("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + url);
        log.error("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + url);
    }
```

This appears to work fine for any js errors, however it doesn't seem to fire for the following:

Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17
Error: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object.

ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which error events do no trigger window.onerror?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886421/which-error-events-do-no-trigger-window-onerror), see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html).